# How to stop running pidgin at logins and disable window hiding feature?

Tags: pidgin

Every time I login into my desktop, pidgin start behind, and sometimes it's annoying me - *e.g. when I'm not connected to Internet or when I don't want to be on-line* - I check startup application list and there's no pidgin listed.
another thing that is very annoying is **hiding window feature** or what ever it called.
assume that you're using **MusicTracker** plug-in, your status is **Busy** and you're **chatting with someone**. when music change, status will change, and then **buddy-list** will **disappear** and **chat window** will **minimize**. Buddy-list is not important but minimizing chat window when you're chatting is annoying, Is there any way to make pidgin stop that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

- Close all running applications then go to System **→** Preferences **→** Startup Applications.
- Click on the Options tab, check **Automatically remember running applications when logging out**.
  [image]
- Close and reboot.

**NOTE:**

- If you want your windows to stop minimizing when your away status changes, then Goto Tools → Plugins and then uncheck **Iconify on Away** plugin.
  [image]
- Alternatively you could stop using musictracker so your status stops periodically changing.

Comment: thanks, it worked. but I think there would be a better way. when I run pidgin from message-indicator it run in background and buddy-list did not shown. thank you anyway :)